# Team Foundation Server: Multiple Identities Found

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Up until yesterday, my connection to Team Foundation Service was working perfectly.

A separate requirement caused me yesterday to rename my computer. After that, there were some errors about the workspace which I was able to fix with the TF command, but I can't find anything about this new error, which arose after I renamed the workspace:

Please note that the blacked-out email addresses are all three identical.

I have no idea how to "specify one of the following workspace specs" from a MessageBox! Any ideas?

TFS for years has been among the worst user experiences I've ever seen.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to guess at a "tf" command line argument set, but, I found that the workspace carried the same name as the computer, after renaming both. So I did this to myself.

After using "tf" to change the workspace name from "WIN8DEV" to "WIN8DEVWORKSPACE" this particular problem vanished.

Answer (score 2):

For me it helped to just sign out from TFS via  the "Configure Team Projects" window, and then log in again.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to TFS DB and refer DefaultCollection db.

1. `[dbo].[tbl_Workspace]` this table is used to store workspace info
2. `[tbl_WorkspaceMapping]` this table is used to store mapping created above.
3. `[dbo].[tbl_WorkingFolder]` this table is used to store working folder mapping.

Exit your tfs client and perform below steps.

1. delete your workspaces causing issue from table `[dbo].[tbl_Workspace]` and `[tbl_WorkspaceMapping]` and start accessing your tfs client by configuring new workspace.

Comment: Where is that DB?